# Angular doesn't load with a mobile connection

Tags: node.js, angular

I've got an angular 6 application hosted on my server, with ssl and https protocol. I can enter on my site from my computer with a lot of connection, but on my mobile phone the loading is very slow... about 3-4 minutes.

I've done network profiling with chrome and I can't see what takes a lot of time, vendor.js takes 3 seconds with a fast connection but with a mobile connection the loading doesn't finish.

Comment: how does it load with chromes virtual device, have you ran a lighthouse audit on the page?

Comment: I've done profiling on my computer chrome with ethernet connection

Answer (score 0):

> but on my mobile phone the loading is very slow... about 3-4 minutes.

Run a bandwidth test on your phone to make sure the connection has the required speed. Go to https://google.com/ and search for "speedtest".

Next, build an empty Angular project and try that instead. Verify it loads quickly.

Once you've verified that the phone's speed is not the issue, then it's likely you're seeing a *dump* of error messages to the console. Even when the console is not visible the cascade of unhandled exceptions will have a negative effect on performance.

You can remotely debug the phone's JavaScript console by using https://jsconsole.com/

Here's an article on how to use it:

https://coderwall.com/p/cvstug/debugging-javascript-errors-on-ios-android-and-other-mobile-devices

Here's a video on it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y219Ziuipvc